# Ionic don't see call-number plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I installed call number plugin on ionic. In fact it created a directory to ionic-native but I have the error "console.warn: Ionic Native: tried calling CallNumber.callNumber, but the CallNumber plugin is not installed.".
How I can fix this error?

Comment: Is this the plugin that you installed ? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number/ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the plugin thath I installed

Comment: This is a straight forward plugin, it should work, without any problem, have you done npm install --save @ionic-native/call-number as well ?. If so, then paste the o/p of ionic cordova plugin ls

Comment: I have already unistalled and reinstalled the plugin but it keeps telling me that is not installed

Comment: Is this the problem only on iOS or Android too ? reason I'm asking is, many plugins fail on iOS.

Comment: I try to install the plugin only to android

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that you installed the cordova plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add call-number
```

Maybe you can try deleting the platforms and adding them again.

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova platform add android
```